# Bounds on spectral radius using chromatic number

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, sp.spectral-theory, lower-bounds, chromatic-polynomial

I am struggling with this question:

> If I have a connected graph $G$ on $n$ vertices and $m$ edges with chromatic number $d$ then how can I give a bound(lower and upper) on its spectral radius in terms of its chromatic number.

There are some properties on the largest eigen value of adjacency matrix  $A$ of a graph $G$.

If  a Graph $G$  is connected then the largest eigen value of $A$ say $\rho(A)$  is positive and it has a positive eigen vector(Perron-Frobenius Theorem)

How can I give  an upper bound on $\rho(A)$ in terms of chromatic number of $G$?

I want the bound to be proved in terms  of chromatic number and in terms of number of vertices and edges of the graph $G$.

How can I do it?

**Note:I checked Wilf's and Hoffmans bound.But I want to find some other bounds which involve using the Perrons Theorem and uses $n,m$**

Comment: There are bipartite graphs with arbitrarily high spectral radius, so you cannot use chromatic number on its own.

Comment: @GordonRoyle;cant we give a lower bound using chromatic numbers too?

Comment: Possibly $\rho(A)\geq\chi-1$?